# How can Different Login for Admin and FrontEnd through LocalStorage

Tags: angular

I am using a Angular2 with Node Js, Express and MongoDb. I have created 2 modules. 1) Admin and 2) Frontend. to a separate folder. But path is given as: 
1) `/` for Frontend and 2) `/admin` for Admin Login. It is generate a token for local storage butt token is generate for admin and frontend for same. So one module logged in after second is automatically logged in.

Is there a way to have one separate web with a different login.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The "tags" applied to your question are meant to relate to the "current question you are asking", and not "the whole stack in use on my project". Right now you have a "front end" or `angular` question since that is what you are using. This is the only tag appropriate to your question. And you could be a bit clearer about what you are asking as well.

Comment: Can you please provide more details/Code, like how you are generating the token and login?

Comment: [Click to Refer Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174300/same-app-with-different-login-frontend-and-backend-in-angular2-in-mean-stack)         For Admin and Frontend @Gourav